# Merging duplicated data objects from the response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, lodash

I have a api response as given below

```
response = [
  { id: 1, val: 'A', date: '28/03/2021', versions: [] },
  { id: 1, val: 'B', date: '29/03/2021', versions: [] },
  { id: 1, val: 'C', date: '30/03/2021', versions: [] },
  { id: 2, val: 'D', date: '31/03/2021', versions: [] }
]
```

Clearly, id: 1's latest value is `C`. I need to transform it as given below

```
response = [
  { id: 2, val: 'D', date: '31/03/2021', versions: ['31/03/2021'] },
  { id: 1, val: 'C', date: '30/03/2021', versions: ['28/03/2021', '29/03/2021', '30/03/2021'] }
]
```

which means, id:1 has three versions and id:2 has only one version.

I tried something like this

```
_.uniqBy(_.orderBy(response, 'date','desc'), 'id');
```

the above code removed the duplicates and showed the latest id:1's value, but not sure which lodash function to use and how to add the versions. Any leads would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let result = [];

let uniqueIds = [...new Set(response.map(x => x.id))];

uniqueIds.forEach(id => {
  let items = [...response.filter(x => x.id == id)];
  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, items.map(y =>  new Date(y.date))));;

  result.push({
    id: id,
    date: maxDate,
    versions :[...items.map(y =>  y.date)]
  });
});
```

Check **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8knnbh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**